# How would I change a color of button per instance of an application?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I would like to color code instances of an application in Windows 7 taskbar. In the example below I would like to

- 1 to be Orange
- 2 to be Yellow
- 3 to be Purple

[image]

How can this be done?

*Getting there... slowly*

I was able to find a program TasKBow Free which does the job halfway

[image]

As you can see it changes the color of a button but it does not provide the 
option by instance. I need those colors to be different per button.

Comment: There might be third-party software that does this, but what you want, is not a feature of Windows.

Comment: I'm ok with any suggestions :D

Comment: [I am not](http://superuser.com/help)

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to ask for "suggestions" but I have tried tinkering with shortcut editing without any success. Right now I'm stumped what to type into a search engine to get a result I'm in need for....

Comment: There's no rule against people suggesting software as a solution to your question.  They just need to follow the guidelines: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments. There is no way to do this natively. Indeed, Windows will stack those Icons if it can and if you let it (which is the default). So you would only see one anyway if you have too many items on the taskbar.

You can change the icons for pinned applications by creating a link shortcut to the original app then changing the icon on the shortcut. But that doesn't help when running it.

Comment: Also neither change the color of the icon on the taskbar.